# Android: Gridview be closed after pressing grid item

Tags: android, gridview, onclicklistener

I am having a gridview of which when a grid item is pressed, it will invoke the detail page of the item, and implemented as follows:

```
public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent)
{
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (view == null) 
    {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gridview_item, null);
        holder.photo_file = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.photo_file);
        view.setTag(holder);
    } 
    else 
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }
    imageLoader.DisplayImage(photoarraylist.get(position).get_photo_ref(), holder.photo_file);      
    view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Public_download_detail.class);
            intent.putExtra("photo", photoarraylist.get(position).get_photo_ref());
            intent.putExtra("user_name", (photoarraylist.get(position).get_user_name()));
            context.startActivity(intent);
            context.finish();   // how to write??
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

### Situation:

The gridview simply open at background when is gone to the detail view, and then when back from the detail view to and forth after opening several times, there are many layers of the gridview page, which when pressing the back buttons the gridview page keep on refreshing and showing.

### Question:

Therefore I would like to implement a way that when a item is pressed, the gridview page to be `finish`. But how can such be written?

```
context.finish();
```

And actually I do not know how to properly switching activities between A and B, when opening B from A, A is always kept opened. How can such be handled actually?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

instead of using **startActivity(intent)**, use **startActivityForResult** to open the details activity and when the user is done with the detailsActivity and wants to go back to gridView , you can continue or start over your process, by **onActivityResult**  method.